# EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids()

Tags: debugging, drupal, drupal-7, entity, entities

I have got this error. I have gone through following article and few more, but none of them having resolve my issue. I know, this error is more generic. I am unable to find the where the cause is.

Note: My Homepage is working well. I am seeing Javascript and CSS are loading perfectly. Apart from homepage, none of other pages are working or redirecting. got 500 server error for those pages.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111610/how-to-debug-entitymalformedexception

Also, installed `Devel` module and put `var_dump(debug_backtrace());` before throw error in common.inc and tried to debug it but could not help to find error. I have checked few tables as per the article but does not any faulty node.

How I can debug this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking for clues to debugging an EntityMalformedException error, I found that when calling `field_get_items()` and the entity is missing, my page broke without a graceful error message. Adding a test for a valid entity before calling `field_get_items()` fixed it.

It was `!empty()` test on the entity variable before calling `field_get_items()`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mostly related to entity_load function in which the entity ids are not getting passed as a argument. So have close look to the custom modules you have written and specially to the entity_load if there are any.